# apt-get upgrade not possible

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, kernel

I'm using
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"

With the command
sudo apt-get upgrade

I get this output:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-56-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

And YES this package was deleted, see
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/canonical_kernel_team/bionic/main/base/linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-56-generic

But what to do now?
I'm not a linux guru. I've just basic knowlede. I've tried several apt and dpkg command versions but found no solution. I've also read through a lot of postings and faq's.

Do I need to step back to linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-53-generic? (and how to do this?)

Best regards and a happy new year!
Sigi

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this does not solve the problem. This linux-modules version is not available...

Answer (score 0):

your issue looks similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305413/unable-to-install-new-packages-due-to-missing-kernel-header); try to look at it and adapt for your problem. In the linked post, the problem is with linux-headers package

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think this can work but where to get the linux-modules version 56? I can find previous version and later ones, but this exact version is not available... ;(