# Unable to install new packages due to missing kernel header

Tags: apt, 20.04, kernel, dpkg

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I am unable to install packages from `apt` or `apt-get`. Whenever I try to install a package, the process terminates with the following error

```
E: The package linux-headers-5.4.0-56 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I tried to install it manually for my kernel but it keeps throwing the same error again

```
$ sudo apt install linux-header-$(uname -r)

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-headers-5.4.0-56 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

To try out from a different kernel, I have booted to an older kernel version (5.4.0-54) from grub but had no luck.

This error prevents me from installing a new package and also from upgrading the existing packages. Any assistance on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Download the package directly from Launchpad: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/amd64/linux-headers-5.4.0-56-generic/5.4.0-56.62.

- If you are using a different architecture than amd64, then change the arch in the URL.
- Look for the 'Downloadable Files' links on the right side of the page. Download the .deb
- Direct link: http://launchpadlibrarian.net/508370134/linux-headers-5.4.0-56-generic_5.4.0-56.62_amd64.deb

Step 2: Put the downloaded package in your /var/cache/apt/archives directory. Apt will look here first for the .deb

Step 3: Try the reinstall again: `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-5.4.0-56`